# How can I convert an array of dates into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python array in the form:

```
K = [ [2022,1,16], [2022,1,18], [2022,2,12], [2022,3,24]]
```

This array contains dates within sub-arrays.

How can I turn it into a Pandas **DataFrame** with 1 column of dates in standard format (`%d/%m/%Y`)?

Comment: In Python, those are called *lists*, not arrays. Anyway - did you try reading the documentation? Did you try to write any kind of call to the DataFrame constructor? What happened when you tried this, and how was the result different from what you wanted? Also, what does this have to do with machine learning? Please only tag things that are relevant to the *problem you are actively asking about*, not the project that motivates the question.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
date_array = [ [2022,1,16], [2022,1,18], [2022,2,12], [2022,3,24]]
date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_array, columns=['year', 'month', 'day'])
date_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_df[['year', 'month', 'day']], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

And if you'd like you can drop extra columns

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
K = [ [2022,1,16], [2022,1,18], [2022,2,12], [2022,3,24]]
dict_t ={"date": []}
import  pandas as pd
for time_list in K:
  dict_t["date"] += [datetime.datetime(*time_list)]
pd.DataFrame(dict_t)
#output
    date
0   2022-01-16
1   2022-01-18
2   2022-02-12
3   2022-03-24
```

you can change the format this way

```
import datetime
K = [ [2022,1,16], [2022,1,18], [2022,2,12], [2022,3,24]]
dict_t ={"date": []}
import  pandas as pd
for time_list in K:
  dict_t["date"] += [datetime.datetime(*time_list)]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_t)
df.style.format({"date": lambda t: t.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")})

    date
0   16/01/2022
1   18/01/2022
2   12/02/2022
3   24/03/2022
```